# Just want to know what am I doing wrong in my code ? Some input is showing correct result and some invalid result?

Tags: java

My program is showing incorrect results for some inputs and correct results for other inputs. I don't know what I'm doing wrong in my code.

In my code, I want to take a String input as a tag and it is valid if the sum of every two consecutive digits of it is even and its letter is not a vowel. I'm considering the letters "A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "Y" to be vowels for this problem.

**Input format:** The first line contains a string of length 9. The format is "DDXDDD-DD", where D stands for a digit (non zero) and X is an uppercase English letter.

**Output Format:** I want to print "valid" (without quotes) if the string is valid, print "invalid" otherwise (without quotes).

**Example** -

```
Input: 13A357-22

Expected Output: valid

My Output: invalid
```

**Here is my code:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Digit {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String vow = "AEIOUY";
        String tag = br.readLine();
        char temp[] = tag.toCharArray();
        if(temp[6] != '-' || Character.isLowerCase(temp[2]))
        {
            temp[6] = '-'; 
            temp[2] = Character.toUpperCase(temp[2]);
        }
        if(!vow.contains(Character.toString(temp[2])))
            System.out.println("invalid");
        else if( (temp.length == 9) && ( (temp[0] + temp[1]) % 2 == 0 ) && ( (temp[3] + 
            temp[4]) %2 == 0 )  && ( (temp[4] + temp[5]) % 2 == 0) && ( (temp[7] + temp[8]) % 2 == 0) )
            System.out.println("valid");
        else
            System.out.println("invalid");
    }

    public static String toString(char[] a)
    {
        String string = new String(a);
        return string;
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran your code with Input of `13A357-22` and it outputted `valid`, not seeing the issue you are getting.

Comment: `13A357-22` contains a vowel (A), then how the expected output is `Valid`? It should be invalid.

Comment: Yes, you're right GURU Shreyansh, I just have to change the print statement. Thank you sir :)

Comment: @user12218554 You should change `if (!vow.contains(Character.toString(temp[2])))` to `if (vow.contains(Character.toString(temp[2]))) System.out.println("invalid");` instead.

Answer (score 0):

i think that it was the way you were testing if it was a number because when i changed it, it worked every time that i tried.

code changes to number detection:

```
else if((temp.length == 9) && IIIL(temp[0],numbers) && IIIL(temp[1],numbers) && 
IIIL(temp[3],numbers) && IIIL(temp[4],numbers) && IIIL(temp[5],numbers) && 
IIIL(temp[7],numbers) && IIIL(temp[8],numbers))
```

new functions:

```
public static Boolean IIIL(char inp, String list)
{
    Boolean end = false;
    char[] delimiter = list.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < delimiter.length; i++) {
        if (delimiter[i] == inp) {
            end = true;
        }
    }

    return(end);}
```

new variables:

```
String numbers = "1234567890";
```